# Programmatically make Amazon purchase?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is anyone aware of an Amazon API that allows you to purchase items programmatically?

I looked at tons of their web services (Product Advertising, MWS, etc.), and none of them seemed to do this.

I found this thread that seemed to suggest there was no solution, but there was no definitive answer: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=45127

Just to be clear, I want to make a purchase with MY payment details, not on behalf of any user. I figured if ANYONE supported this, it would be Amazon. But I realize there may be business (security?) reasons not to support this as well...

Comment: There is a third-party service (which I made) that provides an API for placing orders on Amazon.

[Zinc.io](https://Zinc.io)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**UPDATE 2019/12/10** Even though my answer was accepted as the best answer it's outdated. Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17180929/799155

---

It's not possible – I guess for a bunch of security reasons. Read through the thread you posted in your question ;)

*Lorraine@AWS, Aug 13, 2010 2:02 PM*

> Amazon does not offer APIs to place a customer order. Neither a
>   Corporate Account or the Associate Program will allow you to build the
>   type of solution you are describing.

*Lorraine@AWS, May 13, 2011 4:17 PM*

> Amazon still does not offer this service, to the best of my knowledge,
>   and this isn't something I would ever expect to see included in the
>   Fulfillment Web Service which is specific to the FBA program.

Comment: `@moosgummi` your answer is outdated as of 2012.

Comment: @nurettin is it outdated or not? The year is 2016 and have Amazon provided with an API for placing orders? I've seen their Order API, but it seems to only provide readable actions, not writable.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu I think the Amazon Product Advertising API (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/Welcome.html) is still the best way to go. Although your potential customer has to checkout out via amazon.com itself.

Comment: It is possible with a business relationship with Amazon. See my answer.

Answer (score 41):

http://www.zinc.io/ shows that it is, in fact, possible to do this.

I've read around the net that you could do this by sending crafted _GET responses, although I, myself, am currently trying to figure out which ones to send.

Comment: UPDATE: As of December 2013, I created a complete auto-purchase bot for Amazon that *also* applies giftcards, credit cards, etc. So I know for a fact it is possible. I used CasperJS to do it...

Comment: Using CasperJS to simulate user activity on the website is *not* the same thing as Amazon.com providing an API for automating purchases. It's fragile. Your bot can break if Amazon changes their markup.

Comment: Yeah, no doubt. That's why I have upwards of 100% test code coverage on the beast with 24x7 text message alerts if something breaks ;-) Still, it *is* a programatic solution.

Comment: Hey @TheodoreR.Smith did you by any chance open source that? Checked your github but could not find anything related.

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith Any chance on opensourcing that bot?

Comment: @AdamMoisa Do you know how much I license this out to people?! Holy hell! It's worth at least 5 figures.

Comment: I get that this is quite an old question but the topic is still relevant! I'd like to be able to order programmatically but cannot see where to begin, as Zinc is awfully expensive. Has anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: @AdamMoisa there are some other open sourced amazon bots based on CasperJS. 

https://www.google.com/search?q=amazon+purchase+casperjs+github

Comment: The non-compete / non-disclosure agreement I signed in 2015 is about to expire. I'll recreate it open sourced then.

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith very interested in what you have for an open source solution!

Comment: The NDA expires on 15 November 2020 and I plan on pouring work into it. 

I've made a prototype already. Automation tech GREATLY improved since 2013... I've already made a functional autobuyer for walmart.com, but I don't know if there's interest.

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith -- do you still have this script for Amazon? I am willing to pay. Need to place 25,000 orders.

Comment: Heads up!!!!! My IP lawyer has certified that I can start deving this in earnest on 21 December 2020 :P 16 days from now!

I've already abstracted out the generic WebBot and will be open sourcing that before Christmas!

Comment: I will have an automated Amazon Login bot open sourced before 15 January 2021 and an Amazon Regsitration bot a few days later. By then, i'll have the GitHub project all set up and you guys can star + watch it...

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith, is the bot available?

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith I don't suppose this is available yet, is it? It would be tremendously helpful! Thanks!

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith what's the latest on your autobuyer? Did you open source that already?

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith any news?

Comment: @theodore Free the bot

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith just keeping the alerts coming. Looks like there's a lot of need for this

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith
Is there any update?

Comment: Casperjs/etc bots are not that hard to make, but amazon does change the forms pretty often, so they require a lot of work to keep running