# Purchase on Amazon via API

Tags: amazon-web-services, product

Is there some way to purchase a product on Amazon via the API?

Currently I'm buying several products on daily base, where each product can be delivered to differnet addresses, and each time I have to go over the checkout phase on Amazon (many clicks).

According to my searches (for example [Programmatically make Amazon purchase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048756/programatically-make-amazon-purchase)) it seems that there is no way to purchase a product via the API and I understand the reasons for that.
However, I wonder if there is some other way to automate the process of ordering multiple products on Amazon.

Comment: "Doug" recently commented on [the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9048756/462117) that his product https://zinc.io/ offers this feature.

Answer (score 2):

Another way at it would be to automate the browser with Selenium.  Of course this would require updating the code every time the Amazon website changed.