# Amazon Place order API

Tags: php, ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I have an application in which I need to place order on amazon programmatically.

I had gone through the Amazon documentation, and found that they are not providing Place order API publicly.

I am also aware of this - [Programmatically make Amazon purchase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048756/programatically-make-amazon-purchase)

So I am little curious about **How does [Zinc.io](http://zinc.io/) programatically place an order with Amazon?**

Now I am thinking that to go with zinc.io. But, **Is it a good option to option to use Zinc.io to place order on amazon??**

Please Advice me on this.

Comment: Hello Satish, have you got solution for it ? have you used zinc? or made something else?

Comment: https://Zinc.io is a very good option. As users have suggested on the other posts, it is possible to build something yourself, but it will be prone to breaking as Amazon modifies their website. The Zinc website is plain, but the API is reliable.

Comment: amazon provides that for fulfilled items, https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_MX/fba_outbound/FBAOutbound_CreateFulfillmentOrder.html