# Does AWS SDK for C++ work with Embarcadero C++ builder?

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, c++builder, aws-sdk-cpp

I am looking at developing some applications that utilise AWS services and for this purpose I plan to use [AWS SDK for C++](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp). The documentation does mention support for Visual Studio 2013 or later,  Clang 3.3 or later..etc.

As the development environment I am planning to use [Embarcadero C++ Builder](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder).

Even though in theory these two products seem to be compatible,  I am wondering if anyone has actual experience of using AWS SDK for C++ with Embarcadero C++ and developed any applications and if they came across any major issues when trying to do so.

Any advise would be very much appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Sam

Comment: Were you able to build the AWS SDK with Embarcadero?  I'm getting build errors.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63746074/aws-sdk-c-installation-embarcadero-cmake-error-fpic

Answer (score 0):

> Minimum Requirements for  AWS SDK:
>
> Visual Studio 2013 or later Visual Studio 2013 does not provide
> default move constructors and operators. Later versions of Visual
> Studio provide a standards-compliant compiler.
>
> OR GNU Compiler Collection (GCC) 4.9 or later
>
> **OR Clang 3.3 or later**
>
> 4GB of RAM 4GB of RAM is required to build some of the larger clients. The SDK build may
> fail on EC2 instance types t2.micro, t2.small and other small instance
> types due to insufficient memory.
> from:[sdk Amazon](http://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/LATEST/index.html)

Embarcadero C++ Builder is using Clang-enhanced C++ compiler, so it should be compatible with AWS SDK

But put attention that with Amazon SDK you can not purchase items: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048756/programmatically-make-amazon-purchase)