# AWS SDK C++ installation / Embarcadero: CMake Error -fPIC

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, cmake, c++builder-10.3-rio

I am trying to install the AWS SDK C ++, for use with C ++ builder Embarcadero 10.3 Rio.

After finding some tips on this site and others, I am stuck at this point and wondering about compatibility with embarcadero ...
The error is:
**Error E2075: Incorrect command line option: -fPIC.**

The full message from cmake is:

```
C:\AWS_SDK>cmake C:\aws-sdk-cpp -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -D BUILD_ONLY="s3" -DTARGET_ARCH=WINDOWS -G"Borland Makefiles" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="bcc32c.exe" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="bcc32c.exe" -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=1 ..
-- Found Git: C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe (found version "2.28.0.windows.1")
-- Building AWS libraries as shared objects
-- Generating windows build config
-- Building project version: 1.8.41
-- The C compiler identification is Embarcadero 7.40.36556
-- The CXX compiler identification is Embarcadero 7.40.36556
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Embarcadero/Studio/20.0/bin/bcc32.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Embarcadero/Studio/20.0/bin/bcc32.exe - skipped
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/AWS_SDK/.deps
MAKE Version 5.41  Copyright (c) 1987, 2014 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
MAKE Version 5.41  Copyright (c) 1987, 2014 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
MAKE Version 5.41  Copyright (c) 1987, 2014 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
Scanning dependencies of target AwsChecksums
MAKE Version 5.41  Copyright (c) 1987, 2014 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
[  4%] Creating directories for 'AwsChecksums'
[  8%] Performing download step (git clone) for 'AwsChecksums'
Cloning into 'AwsChecksums'...
Note: switching to 'v0.1.5'.
You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.
If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:
  git switch -c <new-branch-name>
Or undo this operation with:
  git switch -
Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false
HEAD is now at 519d6d9 Don't return 0 on arm please (#22)
[ 12%] No update step for 'AwsChecksums'
[ 16%] No patch step for 'AwsChecksums'
[ 20%] Performing configure step for 'AwsChecksums'
-- The C compiler identification is Embarcadero 7.40.36556
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Embarcadero/Studio/20.0/bin/bcc32.exe - skipped
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/AWS_SDK/.deps/build/src/AwsChecksums-build
[ 25%] Performing build step for 'AwsChecksums'
MAKE Version 5.41  Copyright (c) 1987, 2014 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
MAKE Version 5.41  Copyright (c) 1987, 2014 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
MAKE Version 5.41  Copyright (c) 1987, 2014 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
Scanning dependencies of target aws-checksums
MAKE Version 5.41  Copyright (c) 1987, 2014 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
[  8%] Building C object CMakeFiles/aws-checksums.dir/source/arm/cpuid_arm.c.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 pour Win32 Copyright (c) 1993-2017 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
**Erreur E2075: Option ligne de commande incorrecte : -fPIC**
** error 1 ** deleting CMakeFiles\aws-checksums.dir\source\arm\cpuid_arm.c.obj
** error 1 ** deleting CMakeFiles\aws-checksums.dir\all
** error 1 ** deleting all
** error 1 ** deleting build\src\AwsChecksums-stamp\AwsChecksums-build
** error 1 ** deleting CMakeFiles\AwsChecksums.dir\all
** error 1 ** deleting all
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:224 (message):
  Failed to build third-party libraries.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!**
```

Has anyone successfully installed the SDK with Embarcadero C ++ on Windows?

Do you have any idea to resolve this error?

Comment: Did you install the [CMake support file](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Using_CMake_with_C%2B%2B_Builder#Installing_CMake_and_Ninja) noted in the docs? It should be using bcc32*x* but I see in the text it lists the classic compiler bcc32.

Comment: Has anyone solved this?  I am getting the same error with Embarcadero 10.4.