# Alexa-Skill order product on Amazon

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm currently working on a Alexa skill that find a specific product and order it directly on Amazon and not in another shop system.

The latest informations i have found is a 3 years old post here on Stack overflow.
[Programmatically make Amazon purchase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048756/programmatically-make-amazon-purchase/10899935#10899935)

Is there any solution to make the order on Amazon in Alexa skill?

Comment: This documentation describes the most current implementation to purchasing through Alexa using Amazon Pay: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/amazon-pay/integrate-skill-with-amazon-pay-v2.html

Comment: Did you find any solution?